# Cannot get Error on Page Refresh in production in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am getting this error when refresh the page or manually enter url

```
devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8","@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11","@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7","babel-core": "^6.26.3", "babel-loader": "^8.2.4", "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1","babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",   
  }
```

devDependencies

```
 "cpx": "^1.5.0","env-cmd": "^10.1.0","html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0", "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2", "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
```

scripts

```
"start-server": "node server/index.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run copyindex && cpx .env build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:uat": "env-cmd -f ./.env.uat npm run-script build && npm run copyindex && npm run copyuatenv && npm run renameuat",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prod npm run-script build && npm run copyindex && npm 
  },
```

scripts:

```
"run copyprodenv && npm run renameprod",
    "copyindex": "cpx server/index.js build",
    "copyuatenv": "cpx .env.uat build",
    "copyprodenv": "cpx .env.prod build",
    "renameprod": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('build/.env.prod', 'build/.env', () => { console.log('File successfully renamed!') })\"",
    "renameuat": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('build/.env.uat', 'build/.env', () => { console.log('File successfully renamed!') })\""
```

webpack

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const path = require( 'path' );
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname, entry: './src/index.js', output: {path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),filename: 'main.js',publicPath: '/',},
```

devServer

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
```

module

```
 module: {rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader',},{ test: /\.css?$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]},{test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/, use: 'file-loader'}]},
```

plugins

```
    plugins: [new HtmlWebPackPlugin({template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
            filename: 'index.html'})]};
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I can't understand what is your error. Please specify it correctly.

Comment: on page refresh it is displaying      cannot get /  post
404 error

Comment: the problem is somewhere in your code you are trying to make a `post` request and it's not working.

Comment: problem is when refreshing the no post or get request,
its historyfallApi  error